# Why do I have to place my entire code in $(function(){/* code goes here */});?

Tags: jquery

So I understand that if I have to place this code

```
$("#MyButton").click(function(){/* code goes here */});
```

in an external .js file, I have to reference the script

```
<script src="MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

just before closing the body tag (and not in head) otherwise it doesn't work because the DOM has to be fully loaded before MyScript.js

BUT including my entire code in

```
$(function(){
    $("#MyButton").click(function(){/* code goes here */});
});
```

somehow makes it all work EVEN THOUGH I place the script now in HEAD (instead of just before closing body tag, like earlier)!!

How come??

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the jQuery() function in jQuery do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114925/what-does-the-jquery-function-in-jquery-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$(f)` is shortcut for *"execute function **f** when dom is ready"*

Comment: Yes it is. That ensures you that you will manipulate existing elements.

Comment: @Ankit: It is preferable to use the dom-ready function over moving your scripts to the bottom of the page because it shows your intent rather explicitly.  The only reason you would put your scripts at the bottom of the page is for performance reasons.  My only suggestion is that you do jQuery(document).ready(function() { ...}); instead of the shorthand $(function() { ...}); because it is clearer.

Comment: It is good practice. It's just shorthand notation for `$(document).ready(function { ... });`: http://api.jquery.com/ready

Comment: the whole idea of jquery is to write less code, so I'd say you can make a strong argument for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){ });
```

is an equivalent of

```
$(document).ready(function(){ });
```

So it will be fired when the DOM is loaded. More informations [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 1):

JS executes the moment it's encountered by the browser. If you put your script in the head block, the #Mybutton you want has not yet been loaded. As far as your script is conerned, #MyButton doesn't exist.

But when you do the $(function())... version, it tells JQuery to define the function, but NOT EXECUTE UNTIL the entire page DOM has been loaded. At that point, #MyButton is present and the script will execute as expected.

In real world terms, you're trying to make a sandwich before the bread's finished baking. By using that special notation, you wait until the bread comes out of the oven before starting to spread the butter and mustard.