# What does jQuery(function) or $(function) do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $(function() {} ); do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do)

what exactly does the following syntax mean?

```
$(function() {..}
```

as in

```
$(function () {

    $(".add_folder").click(function () {
```

Does it means only defining anonymos function? or also executing it?

TIA

Comment: It is calling the `$` function with the argument being an anonymous function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114925/what-does-the-jquery-function-in-jquery-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have linked to/closed for the related questions as to "what it does", as to "how" this works:

`expression(...)` *always* treats the result of expression as a function-object and attempts to invoke it. (If the result is not a function-object there is an error.)

`function (...) {...}` -- *in an expression context* -- evaluates to the anonymous function-object. It *never* invokes said function.

`$` is just a "normal identifier" or, an expression in this case. (It is likely that `$ === jQuery` in this example.)

Thus, the above is semantically equivalent of (ignoring property pollution):

```
func = $;
anon_func = function () {...};
func(anon_func);
```

Exactly what `func` does with `anon_func` is up to `func`. In this case, because `func` and `$` and `jQuery` evaluate to the same function-object, the behavior is defined by [jQuery(callback)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

It means the same thing as `$(document).ready(function() {});`

When the document is loaded, it calls the passed in function.  I don't find the `$(function() {})` form very self documenting so I use the `$(document).ready(function() {});` form in my code, though they do the same thing.

See the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The first executes when in global scope, the other is Only defining. So it fires when the element is clicked